# swift firestore check if documents exists

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

using swift and firestore I want to check the "Taken User Names" collection to see if a username has been taken and if it has alert the user it taken otherwise if it's still available I want to create the file.

The gist of what I want to do is outlined below, I can save the data no problem though its the checking to see if its document exists then taking action that I cannot figure out

```
func nextButtonPressed(){

     let db = Firestore.firestore()

    if usernameTextField.text != ""{
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text else { return }
        let docRef = db.collection("Taken User Names").document(username)
        // check if username exists{
        //if exists alert user "sorry user name taken
    } else {
        // if user name doesn't exist 
        db.collection("Taken User Names").document("trinidad")
                .setData(["Taken User Name" : (username)]) {
            (error: Error?) in
                if let error = error {
                   print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                   print("document was succesfully created and written")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In a cleaner way:

```
let docRef = db.collection("collection").document("doc")
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
       if document.exists {
         print("Document data: \(document.data())")
      } else {
         print("Document does not exist")
      }
}
```

Comment: remember that documentSnapshot is optional value, so you just can't write document.exists, because this variable can be null. You can do something like this:             if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot,
               documentSnapshot.exists {
                
            }

Answer (score 6):

```
func nextButtonPressed(){

   let db = Firestore.firestore()

   nextButton.isEnabled = false

    if usernameTextField.text != ""{

        guard let username = usernameTextField.text else { return }

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        let docRef = db.collection("Taken User Names").document(username)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {


                if document.exists{
                    print("Document data: \(document.data())")

                    self.alertTheUser(title: "Username Taken", message: "please choose again")

                      self.nextButton.isEnabled = true

                } else {

                print("Document does not exist")



                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add more details.  Just publishing the code doesn't explain _how_ it works or why it is the proper answer to your question.  Also, please remove the double linefeeds so that your code gets smaller on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
guard let username = userNameTextField.text else { return }

let docRef = db.collection("users").whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).limit(to: 1)
docRef.getDocuments { (querysnapshot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Document Error: ", error!)
    } else {
        if let doc = querysnapshot?.documents, !doc.isEmpty {
            print("Document is present.")
        }
    }
}
```