# how save data to Firebase Firestore with a custom but unique Id?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In swift using Firebase, with:

```
let ref = dbLocations.collection("Data").document()
ref.setData(data)
```

Data added with a document Id like `40rprS6NshDHhZiI8YxJ`

how can I generate an ID as "location1" "location2" or something but with the guarantee the is a unique one on the database?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+sequential+document+id?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set your own ID then you just have to specify it in `document()` as shown below:

```
let ref = dbLocations.collection("Data").document("CUSTOM_ID")
ref.setData(data);
```

This however will overwrite the document if it already so you must [check if document exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224143/swift-firestore-check-if-documents-exists) before writing data. You could use `.setData(data, merge: true)` so if document exists it'll update it instead of totally replacing current data if that suits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I generate an ID as "location1" or "location2"

Using [sequential document IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids) is considered an anti-pattern when it comes to Firestore:

> Do not use monotonically increasing document IDs such as:
>
> - Customer1, Customer2, Customer3, ...
> - Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, ...

> Such sequential IDs can lead to hotspots that impact latency.

So you can create your own unique IDs, as long as you are 100% sure that those IDs are unique.

Moreover, each time you call `.document()` without passing any argument, a new document ID is generated. If you need to have a custom ID then you should consider using:

```
let ref = dbLocations.collection("Data").document("idOfYourChoice")
```

Comment: Hey, doxsi. Can I help you with other information?